# How to track each author's pageviews in wordpress with Google Analytics

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I use the universal tracking code which looks like this:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

I can add the line:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'nav buttons', 4);
```

And it works, but when I try to do this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-Y', 'example.com');

<?php
   if (is_single()){
      echo "ga('set', 'contentGroup1', '".get_the_author()."');\n";
   }
?>

ga('send', 'pageview');
```

To get the author-data, the whole code crashes, and my tracking code stops working.

Anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: As per wordpress documentation get_the_author must be used within the loop (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author). Since GA code is usually not inside the loop this might be a problem.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. The solution was that I did not add the GA code in a file that supported PHP. I added the GA code in the functions.php file instead using add_action( 'wp_head', ...). And this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra double quote `"` in your ga statement before the new line character... not to mention you're using curly quotes in the first/last call.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-Y', 'example.com');

<?php
   if (is_single()){
      echo "ga('set', 'contentGroup1', '".get_the_author()."');\n";
   }
?>

ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still does not work even with your code..

It kinda seems like it doesnt support php.

Comment: Well, is it a PHP file that you're adding this code? Do you see the `<?php` or `if (is_single())` in the rendered page code?

Comment: Ah.. damn! I just assumed that my theme's field for inserting the GA-code supported php. Thanks for your answer! Added the code in the functions.php file instead now.